# Can we enable off-chain workers http client to support web-sockets request?

Tags: offchain-worker, https

As for now it supports rest request, and some duration limitation due to valid reasons. So my question is can we enable or work with web sockets for monitoring data changes , as for now we are only doing on and off connections to the outside world

Answer (score 2):

Phala Network has a design for Fat Contracts called the SideVM (requires deploying local testnet to use for now). You can check out some examples here [Fat Contract Examples](https://github.com/Phala-Network/fat-contract-examples). We also enable HTTPS requests from our Secure Off-Chain Workers so there are many use cases to build.

If you’d like to build on our platform please reach out and I can get you in contact with core team to go into deeper detail on the SideVM implementation.